# Last matching value in DataFrame (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a very large df that I am trying to work on, but the only method I have found so far is using for loops which is taking far too long. I know that it's possible but just not sure how so hoping someone can help. Lets say I have the following df:

```
Date       ID   Name Old_Value New_Value
2018-01-01 101  Bob  10.0      12.0
2018-01-01 102  Tim  9.0       14.0

..... 15 mil rows
```

I need to find a way of taking Bob's New_Value and use that as his next Old_Value so the df would look something as follows:

```
Date       ID   Name Old_Value New_Value
2018-01-01 101  Bob  10.0      12.0
2018-01-01 102  Tim  9.0       14.0
2018-02-01 101  Bob  12.0      9.0
2018-02-14 101  Bob  9.0       7.0
2018-02-14 102  Tim  14.0      19.0
2018-02-21 101  Bob  7.00      6.0
2018-02-21 102  Tim  19.0      16.0
2018-02-23 102  Tim  16.0      14.0
```

The issue is the New_Value cannot be calculated until the Old_Value for each ID is known and the date must be in ascending order over the entire df. So the calculations that return 9.0 as New_Value in row three are dependant on the updated Old_Value (which is 12.0 from New_Value in row one).

Some IDs appear more frequently than others in the df and there is no set sequence to when they appear. The dataframe has upwards of 100,000 unique ids and using for loops is not a viable solution as the run time is in the thousands of hours.

*UPDATE: Thanks for your answers so far, I have added some more information to make it a little clearer.

Comment: Where does that 9 for new value come from?  Next row with Tim?

Comment: please post the for-loop based solution that works but takes too long

Comment: @ScottBoston, the numbers for the example above are arbitrary. I'm looking to take Bob's New_Value from row 1 and use that in a calculation to update New_Value in row three.

Comment: Okay, what does your starting df frame look like?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether I understand your problem completely, but maybe this solution that should work on a dataframe that is sorted on time can help:

first I mimicked your database (which will take most of the time):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time

df_len = 15*10**6
user_size = 100000

now = int(time.time())
df = pd.DataFrame(index = range(df_len))
df['time_delta'] = np.random.choice(60, df_len)
df['time_delta_sum'] = df.time_delta.cumsum()
df['time_sec']= now - df.time_delta_sum
df['user_id'] = np.random.choice(user_size, df_len)
df['New_Value'] = np.random.choice(80, df_len)
df.sort_values(['user_id', 'time_sec'], inplace = True)

df['Old_Value'] = None
df['Old_Value'].iloc[1:] = df.New_Value.iloc[:-1].values
df['Old_Value'].iloc[0] = np.random.choice(80)

df.sort_values(['time_sec'], inplace = True)

df['date_time'] = df['time_sec'].apply(time.ctime)
df = df[['date_time', 'user_id', 'Old_Value', 'New_Value']].reset_index(drop = True)
```

This tail looks like:

```
df.tail() =
                         date_time  user_id Old_Value  New_Value
14999995  Thu May 17 01:14:14 2018    33790        42         23
14999996  Thu May 17 01:14:36 2018    44252        58         75
14999997  Thu May 17 01:15:18 2018    86755         7         45
14999998  Thu May 17 01:15:44 2018    31874        24         72
14999999  Thu May 17 01:16:20 2018    94365        27         29
```

the function that should do the updating

```
def Append_To_Df(user_id, new_value):
    global df
    old_value = df.loc[df.user_id == user_id, 'New_Value'].iloc[-1]
    df = df.append(pd.DataFrame([[time.ctime(),user_id,old_value,new_value]], columns = df.columns, index = [len(df)]))
```

Then call this function with the user id and new value for this user

```
user_id = 3357
new_value = 35

Append_To_Df(user_id, new_value)
```

And the tail of the dataframe will look like:

```
df.tail() =
                         date_time  user_id Old_Value  New_Value
14999996  Thu May 17 01:14:36 2018    44252        58         75
14999997  Thu May 17 01:15:18 2018    86755         7         45
14999998  Thu May 17 01:15:44 2018    31874        24         72
14999999  Thu May 17 01:16:20 2018    94365        27         29
15000000  Thu May 17 01:18:34 2018     3357        37         35
```

Please note that this will only work if the user is already in the database.

Answer (score 1):

This one is more shaped to the example you have provided:

first create the dataframe (with the date column as index):

```
import pandas as pd

column_names = ['Date', 'ID', 'Name', 'Old_Value', 'New_Value']
values = [['2018-01-01', '101', 'Bob', '10.0', '12.0'], ['2018-01-01', 102, 'Tim', 9.0, 14.0],['2018-02-01', 101, 'Bob', 12.0, 9.0], ['2018-02-14', 101, 'Bob', 9.0, 7.0], ['2018-02-14', 102, 'Tim', 14.0, 19.0], ['2018-02-21', 101, 'Bob', 7.00, 6.0], ['2018-02-21', 102, 'Tim', 19.0, 16.0], ['2018-02-23', 102, 'Tim', 16.0, 14.0]]

df = pd.DataFrame(values, columns = column_names).set_index('Date', drop = True)
```

Then define a user id of which you want to update the value:

```
# the user id of which you want to change the value, 101 of Bob in this case
user_id = 101

# get the last line of the user_id, and take its 'new' value as old value and the name
last_line = df.loc[df.ID == user_id, ['New_Value', 'Name']].iloc[-1]
name = last_line.Name
old_value = last_line.New_Value

# apply a function on the 'new' old value to calculate the 'new' new value
new_value = old_value - 4 #(or any other function)

# set the date for the new value
new_date = '2018-02-25'

#update the dataframe
df = df.append(pd.DataFrame([[user_id, name, old_value, new_value]], index = [new_date], columns = df.columns))
df.index.name = 'Date'
```

in this case resulting in:

```
df = 
             ID Name Old_Value New_Value
Date                                    
2018-01-01  101  Bob      10.0      12.0
2018-01-01  102  Tim         9        14
2018-02-01  101  Bob        12         9
2018-02-14  101  Bob         9         7
2018-02-14  102  Tim        14        19
2018-02-21  101  Bob         7         6
2018-02-21  102  Tim        19        16
2018-02-23  102  Tim        16        14
2018-02-25  101  Bob         6         2
```

Comment: Thank you for both of your answers! Really helpful. For the user id variable, is it possible to pass a list instead of just one ID? Or to run it all with a list comprehension? Or should I look at other avenues? Not asking for the code, just a pointer in the right direction. Thanks again!

Comment: Hi, you could use something like this: df.groupby('ID').last() it gives you the last item for every user id, and then you could take a subset of the id's in your list (or the other way around)